# jquery append does not work correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a random select from an already existing select, but it's not working as expected.

It's removing elements from the original for some reason I'm confused as to why

http://jsfiddle.net/t1dukhwz/51/

```
var sizeofmenu = $('.random_menu').children().length;
var myArr = new shuffle(ArrMap(0,sizeofmenu));

var newmenu = $('.new_menu');
$(myArr).each(function(i,v) { 
//console.log(v);
  newmenu.append($('.random_menu').children().eq(v));



});

function ArrMap(start, count) {
    if(arguments.length == 1) {
        count = start;
        start = 0;
    }

    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        foo.push(start + i);
    }
    return foo;
}


function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what's happening is: when you reference `$('.random_menu').children().eq(v)` it is referring to the actual element in the DOM.  So if you append that element somewhere else (in this case the '.random_menu') it removes it from its current location and appends it to the new location.  The side effect of this is that the size of your array shrinks by one, and the indexes you've randomized get blown to hell.

To avoid this, you could simply clone the original array, like so:

```
var original = $('.random_menu').children().clone();
var sizeofmenu = original.length;
var myArr = new shuffle(ArrMap(0,sizeofmenu));

var newmenu = $('.new_menu');
$(myArr).each(function(i,v) { 
  newmenu.append(original.eq(v));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t1dukhwz/58/

Answer (score 0):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1dukhwz/57/) changing

```
newmenu.append($('.random_menu').children().eq(v));
```

to

```
newmenu.append($('.random_menu').children().eq(v).clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

The follwing code sample is working as expceted
keep a a cache

Update code link
http://jsfiddle.net/bibumathew/t1dukhwz/55
{code}

var cacheMenu = $('.random_menu').html();

```
var cacheMenu = $('.random_menu').html();
```

{/code}